# How to show/enable MS Word "Comment From:" pane/commandbar

Tags: vba, ms-word

I recently created a Macro that would search for specific words in a document and insert a comment for each occurrence it find. After the macro is finished, a window pane appears at the bottom of the MS Word "Comment From:" (see figure, red box).

This window pane is an unexpected result of my macro, but I really like it. It makes navigation to the inserted comments easy because each entries are clickable and link to the commented word. It is like a summary log report of the comments my macro has inserted. But there is no code in my Macro that calls this window pane so I really don't know why it appeared. If I manually do what my Macro does, this pane does not appear.

Now, if I close this window pane, I cannot find how to show/disable it again without running the macro I created. I wanted to make it visible again via a Macro or even through Menus or Setting if there is no way for me to do it via macro.

I have tried identifying it by using a For Each loop in CommandBars, but still I failed to identify it. I used Autoit Window Info and it only shows CommandBars in the Control tab.

[image: What window pane is this?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always helps us if you include code to reproduce what you're asking about. That makes tracking things down easier...

These panes can only be accessed directly over the old WordBasic commands from the Word 2.0 days (25 years ago). To display the Comments pane:

```
 WordBasic.ViewAnnotations
```

This will work in both the print view and the draft view. It's a toggle command, so running it a second time will close the pane. If you want to specify on/off:

```
WordBasic.ViewAnnotations 1 'to open
WordBasic.ViewAnnotations 0 'to close
```

To query the state of the pane:

```
'Open the pane if it's not visible
If WordBasic.ViewAnnotations = 0 Then
   WordBasic.ViewAnnotations 1
End If

'Close the pane if it's visible; note the -1!!!
If WordBasic.ViewAnnotations = -1 Then
   WordBasic.ViewAnnotations 0
End If
```

What you're seeing is the old Word interface, before the modern task panes were introduced. In the old days, the window was "split" in order to show additional information, such as Comments (Annotations), Headers, Footers, Footnotes, etc. As a matter of fact, this interface is still the only way to edit the Footnote/Endnote separators and continuation separators...

Back then, people mostly worked in the "Normal view" (today called the "Draft view") and only looked at WYSIWYG as a print preview because that was too slow for real work. As systems became faster, the page or print layout with "real panes" became the standard; these special, split panes fell into disuse and are practically unknown to those who didn't grow up with them.

Comment: Thank you very much, Cindy Meister! I thought it is a CommandBar like what AutoIt Window Info suggests... You are a big help!

Comment: @Leo I'm not familiar with AutoIt, but it's quite possible that "under the covers" a split pane belongs to the CommandBars object model (interesting thought...) Glad the info helped :-)